# Laravel Queues for multi user environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I am using Laravel 5.1, and I have a task that takes around 2 minutes to process, and this task particularly is generating a report...

Now, it is obvious that I can't make the user wait for 2 minutes on the same page where I took user's input, instead I should process this task in the background and notify the user later about task completion...

So, to achieve this, Laravel provides `Queues` that runs the tasks in background (If I didn't understand wrong), Now for multi-user environment, i.e. if more than one user demands report generation (say there are 4 users), so being the feature named `Queues`, does it mean that tasks will be performed one after the other (i.e. when 4 users demand for report generation one after other, then 4th user's report will only be generated when report of 3rd user is generated) ??

If `Queues` completes their tasks one after other, then is there anyway with which tasks are instantly processed in background, on request of user, and user can get notified later when its task is completed??

Comment: yes, the queues will be processed one after another but there could be instances of queues, in my case where I use supervisor to manage queues anytime I see more than 4 instances of a single queue I am not sure how or why but that could be because of multi-core cpu

Comment: @KhanShahrukh as per my knowledge of what I learnt, the reason for your 4 instances of single queue can either be what you said i.e. multi core cpu but, i think more likely it would be number of processes that you would have set in `laravel-worker.conf` in supervisor (as per the documentation), this file can have a parameter called `numprocs` which defines the no. of workers for any queue or say no of instances of any queue...

Answer (score 0):

Queue based architecture is little complicated than that. See the Queue provides you an interface to different messaging implementations like rabbitMQ, beanstalkd.
Now at any point in code you send send message to Queue which in this context is termed as a JOB. Now your queue will have multiple jobs which are ready to get out as in FIFO sequence.

As per your questions, there are worker which listens to queue, they get a job and execute them. It's up to you how many workers you want. If you have one worker your tasks will be executed one after another, more the workers more the parallel processes.

Worker process are started with command line interface of laravel called Artisan. Each process means one worker. You can start multiple workers with supervisor.

Comment: So, In simple terms of what I understood is, these workers are the limit of processes, more the workers, more is parallel processing, Right??

Also, in Laravel Queues documentation, I am confused with Queue Listener, Queue Daemon Workers, and your answer...

What exactly are these workers? How can I configure and manage Workers? How can I start or have more Worker processes, you specified that it is possible with CLI using artisan, but how exactly? You specified that multiple workers can be started using supervisor but how?

Comment: And Up to my knowledge after googling, Supervisor is a process monitor tool for UNIX-based OS(es), so what to use in windows??

Comment: I confirm the documentation about Queues is a bit hazy

Answer (score 0):

Since you know for sure that u r going to send notification to user after around 2 mins, i suggest to use cron job to check whether any report to generate every 2 mins and if there are, you can send notification to user. That check will be a simple one query so don't need to worry about performance that much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes, that I can do, but in background as you said, **check every 2 minutes if there is any report to generate** requires one special table like Queue's `jobs` table, to maintain records of reports that were generated or are pending... So, however, indirectly, it leads to queue like concept... And the problem is, it is not like I will have lesser or neglible requests for report generation, application is required to expect around or more than 100 reports generation a day...

Comment: However I learned queues, how it works and all and now I am stuck with, how can i increase no of queue workers in windows (platform, where i am developing currently)

Comment: Actually I am also laravel developer but i don't recommend using laravel queues, it's depend on platform alot. May be u can try out https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue KUE Queue which use NodeJS and that one is using redis db and u can configure to process how many job at a time easily.

Comment: Ohh... Yeah, but it is true, laravel queues are platform dependent... But even I can't use redis, because I am using MySql at present, and in my application, at some points, I have to use raw queries as well, so it will be a time-consuming task to move from MySql to redis...

Comment: Don't need to move mysql to redis, redis is use only to manage jobs for queue, so u can still use mysql for your php application and report generate also can use php and mysql. Laravel queue is also use something beanstalk like redis, store data on memory.

Comment: Ohh... Means, one other special purpose DB to use in redis for queues... I can try that.... Thanks..